# What is the total number of processes for the fork() in unix?

Tags: unix, operating-system, fork

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
        pid_t pid; 
        pid = fork(); // #1
        if (pid == 0) {
                if(fork() > 0) // #2
                        fork(); // #3
        } else
                fork(); // #4
        return 0;
}
```

I really get confused on #4 because I don't know whether the program will run this else-statement.
Do you guys know what is the total number of processes finally?

And here, there is another program. Again, what's the total number of processes then? Thank you!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() { 
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                if (fork()) {
                        fork();
                        fork();
                 } else
                        fork();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find what you need in the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) manual page, specifically

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>          and 0 is returned in the child.

At a `fork` call, we thus have one process doing the call, but two processes returning: the parent and the (new) child. They will **both** execute **all code following the fork**.
The process will know if it's the child or the parent (and can differentiate its action) based on the return value.

Knowing that in C, all non-zero values are true, it is possible to know if and who executes #4 in the else case: it will be the child, in effect producing a grand-child.

This does sound like homework, so I'll leave the counting to you.

There are multiple answers, depending on whatever we're considering the possibility that fork fails (return code -1) or not. With the given code I assume you can ignore it.